# Resume n jobs to background concurrently

Tags: bash, fish

I have many paused jobs in my shell. I would like to run `bg` for all of the jobs with a maximum four jobs running concurrently.

I know I can use GNU parallel for new tasks but I would like a BASH or fish solution for resuming existing tasks

Comment: `fg` is meaningful for an interactive shell, do you mean N jobs to run and output concurrently on the same shell, and probably get their input from this shell? I think that you could mean N jobs to run each time, at the background maybe, and whenever any of them finishes, a stopped one to resume, so you have always N jobs running.

Comment: sorry I meant bg. yes 

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't fully answer your question but for one at a time you can do this:

```
~ $ sleep 30
^Z
~ $ sleep 20
^Z
~ $ sleep 10
^Z
~ $ for i in (jobs -p); bg $i; wait; end
Send job 3 “sleep 10” to background
Job 3, 'sleep 10' has ended
Send job 2 “sleep 20” to background
Job 2, 'sleep 20' has ended
Send job 1 “sleep 30” to background
Job 1, 'sleep 30' has ended
```

also because this was a recurring problem for me, I made this to manage my processes a little bit better: https://github.com/chapmanjacobd/que